# Marketing Cloud: Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

What exactly is this tool? Here is what I know. I want to make a Decision Split in a Journey. In order to have fields from my Data Extension show up in the Decision Split, I need to create an Attribute List in Contact Builder, set it as 1 to 1, and use it as root.

I don't really understand what I am doing when linking a data extension and mapping some sort of fields across each other. I'm not sure if I should be linking the email fields together or not.

I have several journeys that use different Data Extensions each. Should I have a different Attribute List for each one, or can I combine them all by linking the Data Extensions in an attribute list, or should I really try to have them all work from one Data Extension (this is doable).

I can't find any good documentation that explains this very clearly, everything seems to be so convoluted. Any good documentation you can link me to would be great if answering these basic questions are too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Builder is how you can relate all your disparate data sources to each other to give you a single view of your contact.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/